# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.ascii()

Tags: java, glassfish, google-cloud-storage, guava

I got this error on glassfish server

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.ascii()Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Alphabet.<init>(BaseEncoding.java:453)
at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Base64Encoding.<init>(BaseEncoding.java:892)
at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.<clinit>(BaseEncoding.java:317)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:133)
at utils.GoogleCouldBucket_Utils.initGoogleBucket(GoogleCouldBucket_Utils.java:52)
at controllers.proTektantController.loggedInTryingToRegister(proTektantController.java:783)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2584)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2114)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:287)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am making website on glassfish. I already added amazon bucket support. It works but I had issue with them so I moved to google cloud platform. I try to add google bucket.

```
public static boolean initGoogleBucket()
{
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        InputStream iStream = externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/googleBucket.json");
        if(iStream == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(iStream);
        storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(GCP_PROJECT).build().getService();

        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(GCP_BUCKET,"blob_name3");
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
        String str = "Hello, Cloud Storage!";

        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, str.getBytes());
        System.out.println("time:="+blob.getCreateTime() + ", link:"+blob.getMediaLink());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In debugger i found it failed at "storage.create"

I read online and only one reason which I found is "google-collet.jar". I can not find this jar in my libraries. May be is have other dependence.

Here list of my jars:

```
glassfish4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/<project>/WEB-INF/lib$ ls
BootsFaces-OSP-dist-0.7.0.jar
api-common-1.7.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.11.285-javadoc.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.11.285-sources.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.11.285.jar
aws-java-sdk.jar
aws-swf-build-tools-1.1.jar
bootstrap-1.0.10.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.9.jar
gax-1.30.0.jar
gax-httpjson-0.47.0.jar
gmaps4jsf-core-3.0.0.jar
google-api-client-1.24.1.jar
google-api-services-storage-v1-rev135-1.24.1.jar
google-auth-library-credentials-0.10.0.jar
google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.10.0.jar
google-cloud-core-1.40.0.jar
google-cloud-core-http-1.40.0.jar
google-cloud-storage-1.40.0.jar
google-http-client-1.24.1.jar
google-http-client-appengine-1.24.1.jar
google-http-client-jackson-1.24.1.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.24.1.jar
google-oauth-client-1.24.1.jar
grpc-context-1.12.0.jar
gson-2.7.jar
guava-23.0.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
ion-java-1.0.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
jackson-core-2.6.7.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar
javax.el.jar
javax.mail-api-1.4.6.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.285.jar
joda-time-2.8.1.jar
joda-time-2.9.2.jar
jsf-facelets.jar
jsr305-3.0.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar
jstl-impl.jar
jstl.jar
myfaces-api-2.1.5.jar
myfaces-bundle-2.1.5.jar
myfaces-impl-2.1.5.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar
netty-buffer-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-codec-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-codec-http-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-handler-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-resolver-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar
opencensus-api-0.15.0.jar
opencensus-contrib-http-util-0.15.0.jar
primefaces-6.2.jar
proto-google-common-protos-1.12.0.jar
proto-google-iam-v1-0.12.0.jar
protobuf-java-3.6.0.jar
protobuf-java-util-3.6.0.jar
spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
threetenbp-1.3.3.jar
```

also I have "Glassfish System Libraries" and "JRE System Library[Java Se 8 [1.8.0_161]]"

I am using eclipse. I am familiar with Marven.

Please

Comment: compare the list of jars when you compiled with above list

Comment: I tried to remove amazon. it did not help

Comment: how i can see compiled jars in eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a collision in your Guava dependencies. Some other dependency in your classpath is using a different version of Guava.

I would suggest running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=guava` and `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=guava-jdk5`. This will allow you to find dependency conflicts in your classpath. The `guava-jdk5` dependency is a common culprit that causes this particular error.

More information on conflict resolvement is also available on the Maven site; https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Once you have identified which dependency is causing the conflict, you can introduce exclusion rules in that dependency in your `pom.xml` to exclude the dependencies causing the issue, for example;

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: is anyway to do it without maven? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: There might be something for this in Eclipse. I personally do not use that IDE. In NetBeans you can view the dependency tree of all your dependencies by choosing `View Artifact Details -> Classpath`. I would imagine there is something similar in Eclipse.


Using Maven directly to view this is better in the sense that it allows you to do it regardless of the development environment you are currently in.


Considering it's more or less an industry standard, I would suggest you install Maven separately and learn the basics of it it - it will benefit you in the long run.

Comment: I converted my project to maven but I am so confused with maven. how to add dependences, it updates indexes so slowly.

Comment: You can read more about how to handle dependencies in Maven here, https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will look into maven when i have time or for new project.

Answer (score -1):

I solved problem but downgrade google cloud libraries and use inputstream instead of bytes array. google deprecated this method but with downgraded libraries and with @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") it works.